# What is a word that means "after the next" or double subsequent?

Tags: single-word-requests, footnotes

Let's say that in footnote 20 I would like to refer to footnote 21. Then I could just say "see next footnote for excerpts."

What if I wanted to reference footnote 22? Then I could reference it by number. But what if the numbering isn't static or predictable? Then how could I give a relative reference to it?

Comment: I don't know of a single word for it but the most common way for native speakers to refer to the concept is the phrase "the next but one". This is used in all sorts of contexts, often with the noun inserted between 'next' and 'but' giving constructions such as "the next footnote but one"

Answer (score 2):

"After next" is commonly spoken. For example, "the week after next" skips the next week. As far as having a single word for it, I don't know of one.